# rescuing from Mysql2::Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, mysql2

I have a simple question. I have a join table which has an index that ensure that (col 1, col 2) is unique.

I am adding to that table using mysql2 gem and am trying to catch the Mysql2::Error if the attempt results in a duplicate key error. While I am getting the duplicate key error, my rescue body is not being executed.

```
begin
  self.foo << bar
rescue Mysql2::Error
  logger.debug("#{$!}")
end
```

I am receiving the following error upon executing `self.foo << bar`

Mysql2::Error: Duplicate entry '35455-6628' for key 'index_foos_bars_on_foo_id_and_bar_id': INSERT INTO `foos_bars` (`foo_id`, `bar_id`) VALUES (35455, 6628)

BUT my rescue statement is not being hit! The exception is not be successfully rescued from. What am I doing wrong? If I remove Mysql2::Error and rescue for everything, then it works. But that is bad practice - I just want to rescue from Mysql2::Error which in the event of a duplicate entry.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you checked your log when you are rescuing everything and made sure Mysql2::Error is exactly the right capitalization and everything for what's being thrown?

Comment: I have logged the exception and it is of type Mysql2::Error

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`Mysql2::Error` is wrapped in another exception class now.  Change your code to:

```
begin
  self.foo << bar
rescue Exception => e      # only for debug purposes, don't rescue Exception in real code
  logger.debug "#{e.class}"
end
```

...and you'll see the real exception class that you need to rescue.

**Edit:** It seems in this case it turned out to be `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique`

Comment: Best to rescue `StandardError` not `Exception`: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/rescue-standarderror-not-exception

Comment: It's just debug code to see the error, and although not likely in this particular case it **is** always possible that the code generating the exception has raised an error that wasn't inherited from `StandardError` as it ought to so I still prefer rescuing the `Exception` for these debug purposes.